# R: grepl outputs matches in the wrong order

Tags: r, string, grepl

I have a data frame (called test) with 1 variable and 5,000 rows, where each element is a string.

```
1. "Am open about my feelings."                   
2. "Take charge."                                 
3. "Talk to a lot of different people at parties."
4. "Make friends easily."                         
5. "Never at a loss for words."                   
6. "Don't talk a lot."                            
7. "Keep in the background."                      
  .....
5000. "Speak softly."
```

I am looking to find and output row positions of 3 specific character elements. In this case df object: "Speak softly.", "Take charge.", "Don't talk a lot."

I expect to get the following output;

```
[1] 5000 2 6
```

However, the code that I am currently using for some reason outputs row indices in the ascending order instead of indices ordered as corresponding to their items as above

```
which(grepl(paste(df, collapse = "|"), test[,1])) 

[1] 2 6 5000
```

I am really unsure why this occurs. I tried set grepl-based options, i.e. FIXED or PERL to TRUE in a hope that it would change the result, but it didn't. Also I tried searching for a generic 'reorder' function, but it is doing a very different thing to what is needed here. Finally, I tried removing the which statement, but it simply changes output as binary and produces TRUE, FALSE type output.

**EDIT**

Thank you everyone for help with the solution.

```
lapply(big7 , function(p) {
grep(pattern = p, test[ , 1])} ) # correct order of indices  

lapply(big7 , function(p) {
grepl(pattern = p, test[ , 1])} ) #  TRUE/FALSE for each item in the correct order
```

Comment: Don't use an OR-construction.(There is no implicit ordering of an OR-test.)  Instead use `sapply` with `grep` on the three element vector passed to function(p){ grep(patt=p, x=test[,1]}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this (for the reasons in my comment above (and because grep returns numeric positions):

```
  sapply( df , function(p) {grep(patt=p, test[ , 1])} )
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! For some reason, the code outputs all items as necessary, but it shows .1 as row index of each item. I wonder why it does not show correct row indices.

Comment: I managed to solve this with                                                                                                  
        lapply(big7 , function(p) {
   grep(pattern = p, test[ , 1])} )

Comment: I don’t see any difference in our two solutions. Using lapply should not make any difference.

Comment: yes I agree, not sure why sapply showed .1 next to every element. It's quite strange